# Why is kernel oops behaviour is different between two same fedora19 x86 machines

Tags: fedora, crash, kernel-panic

I have two same x86 machines running fedora 19 .
I see the same kernel panic in both of them on loading a custom kernel module.

one of them shows an oops message in dmesg  while the other just reboots.
Let's say machine A shows oops message and I can still type commands at the terminal.

on analyzing the kdump from machine B using the crash utility, i get same oops signature as machine A

My question is why there is a difference between the two.
Any suggestions on what areas to look at.

BTW there is no difference in both the machine kernels.I run the same module.ko file in both.

Comment: Glad you found the difference -- doesn't have to be a module, could be a separate configuration parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I found a kernel parameter which was different.
sysctl kernel.panic_on_oops 
Which was 1 on the crashing machine and 0 on the running machine.